# Excel/Powershell to extract substring from a URL

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, excel, string, powershell-script

I want to extract root URL from full URL. how to extract that based on number of "/" in that.

for example:

```
https://teams.SharePoint.com/sites/site/communities/subsite
```

from this URL i want to extract below root site(**string before 5th "/"**).

```
https://teams.SharePoint.com/sites/site
```

Please assist how to achieve this in **Powershell** and in **excel**.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell:

Either cast to an `[uri]` type and (re-)assemble the parts

```
> [uri]"https://teams.SharePoint.com/sites/site/communities/subsite"


AbsolutePath   : /sites/site/communities/subsite
AbsoluteUri    : https://teams.sharepoint.com/sites/site/communities/subsite
LocalPath      : /sites/site/communities/subsite
Authority      : teams.sharepoint.com
HostNameType   : Dns
IsDefaultPort  : True
IsFile         : False
IsLoopback     : False
PathAndQuery   : /sites/site/communities/subsite
Segments       : {/, sites/, site/, communities/...}
IsUnc          : False
Host           : teams.sharepoint.com
Port           : 443
Query          :
Fragment       :
Scheme         : https
OriginalString : https://teams.SharePoint.com/sites/site/communities/subsite
DnsSafeHost    : teams.sharepoint.com
IdnHost        : teams.sharepoint.com
IsAbsoluteUri  : True
UserEscaped    : False
UserInfo       :
```

Or use the `-split` and `-join` operators

```
## Q:\Test\2019\07\29\SP_267043.ps1
$Site = "https://teams.SharePoint.com/sites/site/communities/subsite"

$URI  = [uri]$Site
"{0}://{1}{2}" -f $Uri.Scheme,$Uri.Host,(-join $Uri.Segments[0..2])
'-'*50
($Site -split '/')[0..4] -join '/'
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\07\29\SP_267043.ps1
https://teams.sharepoint.com/sites/site/
--------------------------------------------------
https://teams.SharePoint.com/sites/site
```

Note the trailing `/` when joining segments.

Comment: I like this way of getting details from [uri]. Didn't know it before, thanks! Useful!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this in PowerShell (on the SharePoint box).

All of the below examples will result with `https://teams.SharePoint.com/sites/site`

The best way is to call the Root Site Collection's Web:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "https://teams.SharePoint.com/sites/site/communities/subsite"
$web.Site
```

You can try calling the Parent Web for each web (not as useful):

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "https://teams.SharePoint.com/sites/site/communities/subsite"
$web.ParentWeb.ParentWeb
```

or even try calling the Parent's Root Site Collection Web (same result as the first example - all webs will have the same common root site collection web):

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "https://teams.SharePoint.com/sites/site/communities/subsite"
$web.ParentWeb.Site
```

First example is the easiest. The other examples are just to show you the "ParentWeb" property.